# UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView always returning a relative point

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached to a map view in my window (and recognizing gesture simulateously so I can receive events when the map pans). However for some reason I can't figure out, `[UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:]` always returns coordinates relative to the origin of the pan. In fact it behaves identically regardless of what view parameter I pass to it, even `nil`!

I can't figure out why it's not telling me coordinates relative to the view I pass in.

```
self.mapViewPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
self.mapViewPan.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:self.mapViewPan];
```

*

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", translatedPoint.x, translatedPoint.y);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I seem to have misunderstood what `translationInView:` actually represents. It appears to be relative to the origin of the touch regardless (which makes me wonder what its parameter actually affects).

It turns out what I really want is `locationInView:`:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.view];
```

This returns the location of the touch in the view's coordinates.

Comment: you may want to use recognizer.view there. Both reference the same view, but if you refactor this around it could break.

Comment: Actually they aren't the same view. `recognizer.view` (or `sender.view` in my case) represents the view the recognizer is *attached* to, but I specifically want the coordinates of the touch in the view controller's main view, i.e. the superview of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're not using the MKMapViewDelegate methods for this?
[mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:) should let you get the map region when it scrolls.

Comment: The map view isn't the only thing I am tracking gestures on and I don't want to split up the logic. I am getting the same result on my table view as well so I don't think it's anything particular to do with the map view.

Comment: gotcha, looks like you found the answer below.